# I need help in jquery to make array of itemnames

Tags: javascript, jquery

This line is written in html page:

```
<td class="item" valign="middle" align="left" width="55%"><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a>
```

You can see [ITEM_NAME] it fetches all itemnames in the cart.i am able to get last itemname by using  hidden field like this:

First i store [ITEM_NAME] in hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="coliditemnumm" value="[ITEM_NAME]" size="3" maxlength="5" id="Hidden9">
```

And using jquery i fetch hidden field value like this:

```
var  itemname=$('#Hidden9').val();
```

But its overwriten old value and fetch last itemname we added.There should be For loop to store all [ITEM_NAME] in hidden field and then compare all itemnames not the  last itemname.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
var itemname = new Array();
$('input[name=coliditemnumm]').each(function(){
   itemname.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `new Array()` is the same as `[]` - just saying.

Comment: Hi Guerra i used the same code,and set alert(itemname); it shows null

Comment: and you don't need an extra input field for storing the value

Answer (score -1):

ok try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var item_array = [];
   jQuery(".item").each(function(){
      item_array.push(jQuery(this).find('a').text());
   });
});
```

it should do that, and ofcourse include the jquery lib before it

just added a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/animesh/eXZyY/)

Answer (score -1):

You can fill an array with the values of the `<td>` or `<input>`.

Use an HTML class to select them all:

```
<input type="hidden" value="[ITEM_NAME]" class="item-input" />
```

And then loop through them using `each()` and `push()` to append each value to the array:

```
var items = []
$('.item-input').each(function() {
    items.push($(this).val())
})
```

You will have a collection of `[ITEM_NAME]`s stored in `items` for comparing.

Comment: its not getting the [ITEM_NAME].

Comment: Are you getting any error? You can see this working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KsZDm/